# Getting a meaningful report from data

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm fairly new to Google Sheets and know very basic about the functions. I'm trying to create a sheet to keep record of buy/sell of different items and then generate a report where i can see the profit and remaining item in stock , avg buy/sell price etc. Here's a link to [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12dZX7_hgKVQ2CXLAu_vqINCUYxRhN9dvByBskUSK6nU/edit?usp=sharing) and what I've tried.

Please let me know if it can be achieved, if yes what I need to look for, any sample or link to learn in proper direction to achieve what I'm trying to get. Attaching screen shot to give a quick glimpse.[image]
Query I used :-

> =QUERY(A2:F9,"select A,B,Sum(C),Sum(E) group by A,B Label Sum(C) 'Total Quantity',Sum(E) 'Total Price'")

Thank you.

PS. I have it posted earlier in google group as well. I'll link it back there if I come to any solution.

Comment: Instead of adding formulas as images, include them as text (usually formatting as code helps for readability). Looks that you need to use pivot table.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén I have already attached sample sheet link, updated for query in text as well. I tried pivot too but not able to get it the way I wanted, probably my lack of knowledge.

Comment: You could pull out a row from your query using INDEX, based on which row you are in in the result table. Maybe have a look at it later.

Comment: BTW what is the calculation for actual profit?

Comment: Thank you @TomSharpe, that's lot of help to start with, I'll read and see how it all works (not familiar to most of the functions). Actual Profit calculation is in FIFO mode, ie I'll avg the buy rate before the sell happen and deduct the amount of sell eg say item 1 avg buy rate is 11 till the sale date then I'll say 12(sell rate)-11(avg buy rate) =1(actual profit on that sell). Hope I make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a simple and neat way of achieving the layout that you wanted, but you can use Index to pull out a row and column from your query based on the row and column containing the formula like this (for the first column)

```
=if(int(rows($1:3)/3)<=countunique($A$2:$A$9),choose(mod(rows($1:3),3)+1,index(QUERY($A$2:$F$9,"select A,B,Sum(C),Sum(E) group by A,B Label Sum(C) 'Total Quantity',Sum(E) 'Total Price'") ,int(rows($1:3)/3)*2,1),"","Total"),"")
```

Then it works out whether it is the first, second or third row of a group in the report and uses the Choose function to put in the item name, a blank cell or the word "Total".

The second column works in the same sort of way

```
=if(int(rows($1:3)/3)<=countunique($A$2:$A$9),if(mod(rows($1:3),3)<2,index(QUERY($A$2:$F$9,"select A,B,Sum(C),Sum(E) group by A,B Label Sum(C) 'Total Quantity',Sum(E) 'Total Price'") ,int(rows($1:3)/3)*2+mod(rows($1:3),3),2),""),"")
```

The first Mod function is used to work out if it should show "b" or "s" from the query, or a blank, and the second Mod function works out whether it should be the  "b" or "s" row of the query.

The third column is also similar

```
=if(int(rows($1:3)/3)<=countunique($A$2:$A$9),if(mod(rows($1:3),3)<2,index(QUERY($A$2:$F$9,"select A,B,Sum(C),Sum(E) group by A,B Label Sum(C) 'Total Quantity',Sum(E) 'Total Price'") ,int(rows($1:3)/3)*2+mod(rows($1:3),3),3),L11-L12),"")
```

The first Mod function is used to work out if it should show the quantity from the query, or the difference of the two previous rows, and the second Mod function works out whether it should be the  "b" or "s" row of the query.

The fourth column is almost identical to the second one.

```
=if(int(rows($1:3)/3)<=countunique($A$2:$A$9),if(mod(rows($1:3),3)<2,index(QUERY($A$2:$F$9,"select A,B,Sum(C),Sum(E) group by A,B Label Sum(C) 'Total Quantity',Sum(E) 'Total Price'") ,int(rows($1:3)/3)*2+mod(rows($1:3),3),4),""),"")
```

[image]

(I couldn't work out how the Actual Profit should be calculated).

Comment: The work was to maintain inventory of any small shop which buy items in different rates. This is one page record all and then see what is in stock, what is profit on sell etc as report.